# Some services are not able to be constructed ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Good day. Can someone help me with this problem in Visual Studio? I am trying to create my first web app but there is an error I encountered.

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: LearnMUSIC.Core.Application._Interfaces.IAppDbContext Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: LearnMUSIC.Data.AppDbContext': Implementation type 'LearnMUSIC.Data.AppDbContext' can't be converted to service type 'LearnMUSIC.Core.Application._Interfaces.IAppDbContext') (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[LearnMUSIC.Application.SongSheets.Commands.CreateSongSheet.CreateSongSheetCommand,System.Int64] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: LearnMUSIC.Application.SongSheets.Commands.CreateSongSheet.CreateSongSheetCommandHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'LearnMUSIC.Interfaces.IAppDbContext' while attempting to activate 'LearnMUSIC.Application.SongSheets.Commands.CreateSongSheet.CreateSongSheetCommandHandler'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at LearnMUSIC.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Importants\Programming 101\Web Personal Projects\LearnMUSIC\LearnMUSIC\Program.cs:line 16

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: LearnMUSIC.Core.Application._Interfaces.IAppDbContext Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: LearnMUSIC.Data.AppDbContext': Implementation type 'LearnMUSIC.Data.AppDbContext' can't be converted to service type 'LearnMUSIC.Core.Application._Interfaces.IAppDbContext'

Inner Exception 2:
ArgumentException: Implementation type 'LearnMUSIC.Data.AppDbContext' can't be converted to service type 'LearnMUSIC.Core.Application._Interfaces.IAppDbContext'
```

This is my Startup.cs

```
namespace LearnMUSIC
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddControllers();
      services.AddCors();

      services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options => Configuration.Bind("JwtSettings", options))
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options => Configuration.Bind("CookieSettings", options));

      services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
      services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
      {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebAPIv5", Version = "v1" });
      });
      services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LearnMUSICDbConnectionString"))
                  .UseLazyLoadingProxies());

     

      //services.AddHostedService<MembershipStatusUpdateService>();

      // Configure DI
      this.ConfigureDI(services);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAPIv5 v1"));
      }

      app.UseHttpsRedirection();

      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200"));

      //app.UseAuthentication();

      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
      });
    }

    private void ConfigureDI(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      //DbContext
      //services.AddScoped(typeof(IAppDbContext), typeof(AppDbContext));
      services.AddScoped(typeof(IAppDbContext), typeof(AppDbContext));

      services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo());

      // AutoMapper
      services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile));

      // Fluent Validation
      services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestValidationBehavior<,>));
    }
  }
}
```

This is my AppDbContext

```
namespace LearnMUSIC.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext, IAppDbContext
    {
        public DbSet<SongSheet> SongSheets { get; set; }

        public AppDbContext() { }

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
          base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
          base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

          //modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();

          modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(AppDbContext).Assembly);
        }
  }
}
```

This is my IAppDbContext

```
namespace LearnMUSIC.Interfaces
{
    public interface IAppDbContext
    {
        DbSet<SongSheet> SongSheets { get; set; }

        /******************************************************************************/

        EntityEntry Remove(object entity);

        void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<object> entities);

        int SaveChanges();

        Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I have tried to solve this but it doesnt work

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Although your `AppDbContext` implements `IAppDbContext` it appears to be a different version: `LearnMUSIC.Interfaces.IAppDbContext` vs `LearnMUSIC.Core.Application._Interfaces.IAppDbContext` that the error states. These are not the same

Comment: @phuzi bro thank you for the comments! And you are right, the wrong links cause the error. Thank you